# XAMPP: Ubuntu LTS 18.04 xampp.run command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, xampp

I update my `AWS` instance from ubuntu `16` to `18.04`.

Currently I have the xampp installer with this name

`xampp-linux-x64-7.2.2-0-installer.run`

located at `user@ip:~$`

I tried to run this command `sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-7.2.2-0-installer.run`

But the problem is when I tried to run this command

`sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-7.2.2-0-installer.run`

Terminal says

`sudo: ./xampp-linux-x64-7.2.2-0-installer.run: command not found`

Is there anything I need to do first?

Comment: Have you tried running it with an absolute path?

Comment: Don't use XAMPP on a production system. It's a dev tool with insecure settings and should only be used on your dev machine. Ubuntu comes with everything you need already.